# BasiliskII in12.04

Tags: 12.04, games, gtk3, libraries, emulation

I'm trying to install Basilisk2 on 12.04. I converted the rpm from http://basilisk.cebix.net/#download to deb. Running it, however, gives me:

BasiliskII: error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-1.2.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Any ideas?

Comment: If possible, please consider closing some of your other open questions by [selecting the best answer](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1137/how-do-i-accept-an-answer) (if they have one). Consider which answers have been useful and need an upvote. We need users to maintain their questions so that the site can be an effective tool for the next person with your problems. For more details on best practices consider reading [the FAQ on asking questions](http://askubuntu.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 1):

Try this, source: [error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-1.2.so.0:](http://n3wt0n.com/blog/how-to-install-introversions-uplink-in-ubuntu-9-10-or-higher/)

Download the following deb files ...

```
wget http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gtk+1.2/libgtk1.2_1.2.10-18.1build2_i386.deb
wget http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/glib1.2/libglib1.2ldbl_1.2.10-19build1_i386.deb
wget http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gtk+1.2/libgtk1.2-common_1.2.10-18.1build2_all.deb
```

You can swap out the ‘ca’ part of the url with ‘us’ or whatever your Ubuntu repository country code might be.

Now, inside the directory you downloaded them to, run

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```